# Can I have two Spring Boot Camunda applications in same db with different schema

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, camunda

I am trying to start two different Spring Boot Camunda applications. The first one boots perfectly fine, and creates the table and everything in the DB. However when I try to boot the second application it fails. Just to be clear, I want the applications to experience their schema as their own database if that makes sense. The error I get when booting the second Spring Boot Application is:

```
ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "act_ge_property" does not exist
  Position: 15
### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Property.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.PropertyEntity.selectProperty-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select * from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = ?
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "act_ge_property" does not exist
  Position: 15
```

I only have one Postgres DB, but the applications connect to the DB with different username/password. Their user has it's own schema, and does not have any access to the other schemas in the DB. 
The following application properties are set for both applications: `camunda.bpm.datasource.schema-update=true`.
After reading the documentation on Camunda I can see that `.schema-update=true` should create the tables if they don't exist. 
I don't understand why the second application does not create the tables.

For the Postgres schema configuration I create them with the following commands:

```
CREATE USER applicationName WITH PASSWORD 'r4nd0m';
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION applicationName;
```

I don't know if the issue is with configuring the Camunda applications or with privileges/creation regarding the schemas.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. This project shows you how to configure two independent Camunda instances, which use two separate schemas within the same database.

https://github.com/rob2universe/two-camunda-instances

The essential properties are:

```
Spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?autoReconnect=true
  username: cam1
  password: cam1
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
server.port: 8081
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /cam1
camunda:
  bpm:
    database:
      schema-name: cam1
      table-prefix: cam1.
```

Comment: Which is the part that solves the multiple schemas problem there? Value of annotation or application properties?

Comment: Updated the project to use two schemas with same DB. Setting schema-name and table-prefix is the important part https://github.com/rob2universe/two-camunda-instances/blob/71afa9810a2e027ef894384e2880855c8bcc7d6a/cam1instance/src/main/resources/application.yaml#L20